# Good way to obtain an EV SSL certificate for personal use?

Tags: tls, certificate-authority

I would like to obtain some sort of digital certificate for personal use.  I would like to use this for encrypting and signing e-mails, digitally signing contracts, and for providing authentication of my personal website.

In particular, I want this certificate to have a paper trail associated with it, so that the recipient of an e-mail signed with this certificate could be reasonably confident it came from me, Adam L. Taylor, a US citizen with a particular Social Security number.  I am willing to spend money to obtain such a certificate.

How would I do this?

Comment: I think this question is borderline case 1 from http://security.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask "every answer is equally valid" and ""

Comment: Would PGP provide what you need? It's free.

Comment: Edited to hopefully be less borderline.

Comment: I don't think PGP would do it.  For instance, it wouldn't provide an assurance that the public key is associated with a person with my legal name.

Comment: There are a growing number of services that will provide this functionality (the recent RSA conference had a few vendors). Unfortunately, you are likely needing to look for a product/service, which would put this question out of scope for the site. As for the question of a run-of-the-mill cert from a CA, Trey's answer below is probably the closest you will get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EV SSL Certificates aren't that expensive at all the CA's. DigiCert's are less than $300.00 per year at the time of this writing.

As far as getting one for personal use that part might be a little tricky because they want to verify your business via one of 3 business directory verification services.
1.) data.com
2.) Dun and Bradstreet
3.) Google My Business

That said you could easily incorporate a business (your name consulting LLC.)(price varies by state), then register it in one of the business verification services (that part is free), then finally purchase an EV SSL Certificate for your business.

Each CA may have a slightly different process and pricing. DigiCert is probably not the least expensive but this is one way to get one. All of this can definitely be done for well under $1000.00 but I'm not sure what the least expensive combination would be. That said it would be trivial to do price comparisons of the CA's and also the price comparison of registering a company in each state.

Just to avoid potential legal complexities I'd avoid registering a company in another country although I suspect it would be even cheaper.

Note: There may be other ways to do this but from my experience the business verification part was required.

Answer (score 1):

One point of clarification that I think is needed here is that EV SSL doesn't provide signing emails and digitally signing contracts. It is solely for browsers to recognize that the website is owned and operated by a verified business.

With that in mind then, you could get a non-EV SSL (TLS) certificate. It is cheaper than an EV certificate and provides the same technical security that an EV certificate provides.

For signing emails, you have two options:

- S/MIME
- GPG/PGP

Both have their pros and cons. Primarily, S/MIME is not free, but is usually easier to use in email clients, while GPG is free, but can be more difficult to get integrated with email clients.

For signing contracts digitally, that is a bit more open-ended. You can technically use GPG or S/MIME as authentication of who you are, but I've never experienced a digital contract allowing signing with any of the options discussed.

Comment: How is S/MIME not free? The standards are open; I know one implementation (MS Outlook) that is (usually) paid and (always) restricted, but two implementations (OpenSSL and BouncyCastle) that are opensource and no-cost; it's not harder to find no-cost certs than it is for SSL/TLS, and IME secure email is often for a group small and stable enough you *could* do your own CA, which is less often true (though sometimes) for websites or even Internet mailservers. OTOH GnuPG is opensource and no-cost, but pgp.com-now-Symantec is not.

Comment: S/MIME is not free because you have to purchase a cert from a CA. It's not the implementation OP is asking about, but the certs. You can of course self-sign, but that doesn't provide the integrity checking that OP is looking for. And yes, you can find free certs. Let's not distract from the question.

Comment: But if I got an EV X.509 cert, I could still use that to sign e-mails using S/MIME, correct?  And then the recipients of those e-mails would have some extra assurance that, for instance, the name I give is really my legal name.